# Table migration issue while adding foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, yii2

My one file contain the below main table:

```
public function up()
{
    $this->createTable('{{%users}}', [
        'id' => 'pk',
        'uid'=> 'VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL',
        'mydate' => Schema::TYPE_INTEGER . ' NOT NULL',
        'state' => "ENUM('INA','ACT') " . ' NOT NULL',
        'setting' => Schema::TYPE_INTEGER . ' NOT NULL',
    ],'ENGINE=InnoDB'
    );
}
```

The child table which reference to the `uid` of the above table is:

```
 $this->createTable('{{%xyztable}}', [
            'id'=>'pk',
            'uid' => 'integer NOT NULL',
            'server_time' => Schema::TYPE_INTEGER . ' NOT NULL',
            'answer' => 'VARCHAR(135) NOT NULL',
        ],'ENGINE=InnoDB'
    );

    $this->addForeignKey('fk_unique_id',"{{%xyztable}}", 'uid', '{{%users}}', 'uid', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE');
```

On calling migration I am getting the following error

```
Error Info:
Array
(
    [0] => HY000
    [1] => 1215
    [2] => Cannot add foreign key constraint
)
```

I spent more than a hour but unable to figure out this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create foreign key:

**1)** Both columns should have the same type.

You have different types (*string* and *integer*):

```
'uid' => 'VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL',
```

and

```
'uid' => 'integer NOT NULL',
```

**2)** In the table that the foreign key references to connected column should have index.

In your code this is also missing.

In migration you can create index using [createIndex()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-migration.html#createIndex%28%29-detail) method.

Comment: Thanks I have added the index and changed the uid to integer now all works fine.